# How to quickly copy *specific multiple* files?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, file-transfer, cmd.exe

Say I have a list of filenames like these,

```
file01.001
file02.abc
fiAl.12x
```

ect. All with full extensions.

They are all in the main folder C:\ABC. Some files will be in subfolders or even in subsubfolders.

1) What's the quickest way to *use this list* and copy all files into one single folder, say D:\myfolder?

2) How to copy all files in the list, but also preserve the folder structure?

Thanks!

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I know you are not a "script writing service". I am only suggesting that something like a script that might be really easy. I have deleted the line where specifically says "I want a .bat script." I believe the rest of the post has two *specific problems*.

Comment: Right. Then you better start learning. - [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command - would be a good start.

Comment: - [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) - Copy one or more files to another location.

Comment: - [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.

Comment: Your job is to have a go and try to put together `for /f`, `dir` and `copy`. I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I know copy and dir as well as several other simple DOS command. I do believe copy does not automatically search the subfolders. Yes, loop is something that I need (and currently experimenting)

Comment: `copy` can't do subfolders, but `xcopy` can.

Comment: @BenN I will try that.

Comment: You should type Xcopy /?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this : ***[XCOPY Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)***

Example :
To copy a folder including all subfolders

```
XCOPY C:\ABC\* D:\myfolder /s /i
```

> /S    Copy folders and subfolders
>
> /I    If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
>            e.g. when the destination does not exist.